# WPF: ItemsControl with scrollbar (ScrollViewer)

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, itemscontrol, scrollviewer

I followed [this](http://compilewith.net/2008/05/making-itemscontrol-scroll.html) small "tutorial" on how to add a scrollbar to an ItemsControl, and it works in Designer view, but not when I compile and execute the program (only the first few items show up, and no scrollbar to view more - even when VerticalScrollbarVisibility is set to "Visible" instead of "Auto").

Any idea on how to solve this?

---

This is the code I use to show my items (normally I work with Databinding, but to see the items in my Designer I added them manually):

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="itemCtrl" Style="{DynamicResource UsersControlStyle}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            </StackPanel>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

    <uc:UcSpeler />
    <uc:UcSpeler />
    <uc:UcSpeler />
    <uc:UcSpeler />
    <uc:UcSpeler />
</ItemsControl>
```

---

And this is my Template:

```
<Style x:Key="UsersControlStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ItemsControl}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ItemsControl}">
                <Border SnapsToDevicePixels="true" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                    <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
                        <ItemsPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 302, accepted):

To get a scrollbar for an `ItemsControl`, you can host it in a `ScrollViewer` like this:

```
<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
  <ItemsControl>
    <uc:UcSpeler />
    <uc:UcSpeler />
    <uc:UcSpeler />
    <uc:UcSpeler />
    <uc:UcSpeler />
  </ItemsControl>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: It's so obvious when you see it... As I'm coming from Windows Forms, I often find myself stuck in the wrong mindset. It seems that WPF rights a lot of wrongs... +1.

Comment: Thanks -very helpful.  I agree with Lette that my WinForms brain doesn't "get" this initially.

Comment: I just tried this right here and it still did not work. The ItemsControl flows right off its parent container and no ScrollBar is visible at all.

Comment: @Ristogod If you host the ScrollViewer inside something that lets its content grow as much as needed, for example a StackPanel, scrolling will not work. What's the parent container? Try setting a fixed height on either the ScrollViewer or the parent, does that help?

Comment: I've got a question for you Oskar (or anyone else).  I had the ItemsControl within a StackPanel, and like you said, it didn't allow the scrollbars if the ScrollViewer to appear.  So I got rid of the stack panel and put a fixed maximum height to the scroll viewer.  OK, that does work, but I don't quite want that, either, because I want the user to be able to resize the window.  How do I account for that?

Comment: @Rod You can host the ScrollViewer in a DockPanel or a Grid instead of a StackPanel to achieve this.

Comment: I'm late to the party here, but doesn't this disable virtualization? Not saying that everything needs virtualization - just trying to find a solution that doesn't disable virtualization.

Comment: This answer explains how to achieve scrolling without sacrificing item virtualization, which can improve performance when you have many items: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2784220/24874

Answer (score 98):

You have to modify the control template instead of ItemsPanelTemplate:

```
<ItemsControl >
    <ItemsControl.Template>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <ScrollViewer x:Name="ScrollViewer" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                <ItemsPresenter />
            </ScrollViewer>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.Template>
</ItemsControl>
```

Maybe, your code does not working because StackPanel has own scrolling functionality. Try to use [StackPanel.CanVerticallyScroll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.stackpanel.canverticallyscroll.aspx) property.

Comment: The StackPanel CanVerticallyScroll property didn't work, I'm afraid.

Comment: StackPanel CanVerticallyScroll didnt work but the code example given here worked for me. Thanks

Comment: This works. I am looking for making scrollviewer inside instead of outside, because https://github.com/punker76/gong-wpf-dragdrop requires it.

Comment: I had to add a maxheight to my itemscontrol for this to work

Answer (score 3):

Put your ScrollViewer in a DockPanel and set the DockPanel MaxHeight property

```
[...]
<DockPanel MaxHeight="700">
  <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
   <ItemsControl ItemSource ="{Binding ...}">
     [...]
   </ItemsControl>
  </ScrollViewer>
</DockPanel>
[...]
```