# Virtualizing an ItemsControl?

Tags: wpf, virtualization, itemscontrol, virtualizingstackpanel

I have an `ItemsControl` containing a list of data that I would like to virtualize, however `VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"` does not seem to work with an `ItemsControl`.

Is this really the case or is there another way of doing this that I am not aware of?

To test I have been using the following block of code:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=AccountViews.Tables[0]}"
              VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True">
<ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <TextBlock Initialized="TextBlock_Initialized"  
                   Margin="5,50,5,50" Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
    </DataTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

If I change the `ItemsControl` to a `ListBox`, I can see that the `Initialized` event only runs a handful of times (the huge margins are just so I only have to go through a few records), however as an `ItemsControl` every item gets initialized.

I have tried setting the `ItemsControlPanelTemplate` to a `VirtualizingStackPanel` but that doesn't seem to help.

Answer (score 249, accepted):

There's actually much more to it than just making the `ItemsPanelTemplate` use `VirtualizingStackPanel`. The default `ControlTemplate` for `ItemsControl` does not have a `ScrollViewer`, which is the key to virtualization. Adding to the the default control template for `ItemsControl` (using the control template for `ListBox` as a template) gives us the following:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding AccountViews.Tables[0]}">
  <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <TextBlock Initialized="TextBlock_Initialized"
                 Text="{Binding Name}" />
    </DataTemplate>
  </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>

  <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
      <VirtualizingStackPanel IsVirtualizing="True"
                              VirtualizationMode="Recycling" />
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
  </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

  <ItemsControl.Template>
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ItemsControl">
      <Border BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
              BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
              Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
        <ScrollViewer CanContentScroll="True" 
                      Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                      Focusable="False">
          <ItemsPresenter />
        </ScrollViewer>
      </Border>
    </ControlTemplate>
  </ItemsControl.Template>
</ItemsControl>
```

(BTW, a great tool for looking at default control templates is [Show Me The Template](https://sellsbrothers.com/2091))

Things to notice:

You have to set `ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"`, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1924089/listbox-virtualizingstackpanel-and-smooth-scrolling-in-wpf) for why.

Also notice that I put `VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling"`. This will reduce the numbers of times `TextBlock_Initialized` is called to however many TextBlocks are visible on the screen. You can read more on UI virtualization [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20150708100804/http://www.zagstudio.com:80/blog/497)
.

EDIT: Forgot to state the obvious: as an alternate solution, you can just replace `ItemsControl` with `ListBox` :)
Also, check out this [Optimizing Performance on MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cc716879(v=vs.100).aspx) and notice that `ItemsControl` isn't in the "Controls That Implement Performance Features" table, which is why we need to edit the control template.

Comment: Thank you, that is exactly the sort of thing I was looking for! I was looking for a different kind of selection behavior than a listbox and at the time I thought it would be easiest to do with an items control.

Comment: If this itemscontrol is further nested you should also give it a height. Otherwise the scrollviewer isn't shown.

Comment: "Also notice that I put VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode=Recycling". Isn't it supposed to be in the sample you provide?

Comment: Does virtualization also work when wrap `ItemsControl` into `ScrollViewer` instread adding `Scroll` to `ControlTemplate` ?

Comment: @DavidN Where or how can I put the column headers in your solution?

Comment: If I encapsulate the `ScrollViewer` with a `VirtualizingStackPanel`, then the performance drops drastically (I think virtualization then doesn't work anymore)

Comment: Show Me The Template is now a broken link

Comment: For some reason my content isn't scrolling when I scroll the scrollbar. Any idea what might be causing this ?

Comment: I was looking for a solution from 2 to 3 months. Finally, This is the solution I want. I replaced my code with suggested one and the application is working so smoothly. Thank you so much.

Comment: There is one drawback with ```ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"``` which is necessary for virtualization to work, in that the item instead of pixel based handling will cause unwanted spaces at the end of the list. This however can be fixed since .NET 4.5 by adding ```VirtualizingPanel.ScrollUnit="Pixel" VirtualizingPanel.IsContainerVirtualizable="True"``` to the ```ItemsControl```

Answer (score 55):

Building on DavidN's answer, here is a style you can use on an ItemsControl to virtualise it:

```
<!--Virtualised ItemsControl-->
<Style x:Key="ItemsControlVirtualizedStyle" TargetType="ItemsControl">
    <Setter Property="VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <VirtualizingStackPanel />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ItemsControl">
                <Border
                    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding Border.BorderThickness}"
                    Padding="{TemplateBinding Control.Padding}"
                    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding Border.BorderBrush}"
                    Background="{TemplateBinding Panel.Background}"
                    SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
                >
                    <ScrollViewer Padding="{TemplateBinding Control.Padding}" Focusable="False">
                        <ItemsPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding UIElement.SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

I do not like the suggestion to use a ListBox as they allow the selection of rows where you do not necessarily want it.

Answer (score -4):

It is just that the default `ItemsPanel` isn't a `VirtualizingStackPanel`.  You need to change it:

```
<ItemsControl>
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <VirtualizingStackPanel />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: I am down voting it as the solution is incomplete. You need to use a scrollviewer in the template to enable virtualization.