# How to render usercontrols separately

Tags: .net, wpf, multithreading, user-controls, ui-thread

I have a UserControl drawing the datacontext with Itemscontrol etc. I'm having three objects of the same usercontrol but with different datacontexts which is initialized on startup of the program. The problem is that the datacontext is so big so it's drawing about 2000 UIelements on each of the objects. This takes so much time and what really is annoying me is that WPF is running in a single UIThread, so my computer is using 1/8 of the total CPU power to draw this. How can I make this faster?

The code (DynamicShelViewModel is a usercontrol)

```
dataContextBestSellers = new DynamicShelfViewModel(_config, dataRepository, ProductSelectionMode.BestSellers);
dataContextNormal = new DynamicShelfViewModel(_config, dataRepository, ProductSelectionMode.Normal);
dataContextFull = new DynamicShelfViewModel(_config, dataRepository, ProductSelectionMode.AllProducts); 
ScrollGrid = new Grid();
ScrollGrid.Children.Add(dataContextBestSellers);
ScrollGrid.Children.Add(dataContextNormal);
ScrollGrid.Children.Add(dataContextFull);
```

This takes about 2 minutes to accomplish.

This is the XAML code of DynamicShelfViewModel

```
<Grid>
    <ItemsControl x:Name="ShelvesControl" VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"
                  VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling" DataContext="{Binding}" Width="{Binding Size.Width}"
                  VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="{Binding Size.Height}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding ShelvesInViewPort}">
      <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>


          <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Stretch  " HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Orientation="Vertical" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
      </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
      <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <Grid Name="ShelfGrid" Height="{Binding Height}" MaxHeight="{Binding Height}"
                DataContext="{Binding}">
            <Grid.Background>
              <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding Color}" />
            </Grid.Background>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
              <RowDefinition Height="*" />
              <RowDefinition Height="{Binding SplitterSize}" />

            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Name="stretchingLabel" Height="{Binding SplitterSize}" Padding="0" Grid.Row="1"
                       VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
              <TextBlock.Background>
                <ImageBrush
ImageSource="{Binding Converter={Utilities1:FancySourceConverter}, ConverterParameter=Images/ShelvesImages/shelfhorisontal.png}" />
              </TextBlock.Background>
              <Grid VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                    Width="{Binding ElementName=stretchingLabel,Path=ActualWidth}"
                    Height="{Binding ElementName=stretchingLabel,Path=ActualHeight}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                  <RowDefinition Height="0.24*" />
                  <RowDefinition Height="0.62*" />
                  <RowDefinition Height="0.24*" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <my:CategoryLine VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="1"
                                 DataContext="{Binding ElementName=ShelfGrid, Path=DataContext}">
                </my:CategoryLine>
              </Grid>
            </TextBlock>

            <TextBlock Name="stretchedLabel" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                       Grid.Row="0" Padding="0">
              <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Products}" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                  <ItemsPanelTemplate>

                    <UniformGrid DataContext="{Binding}"
                                 Width="{Binding ElementName=stretchedLabel, Path=ActualWidth}"
                                 MaxHeight="{Binding ElementName=stretchedLabel, Path=ActualHeight}"
                                 Height="{Binding ElementName=stretchedLabel, Path=ActualHeight}"
                                 Columns="{Binding Path=DataContext.Slots, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Grid}}}" Rows="1"
                                 VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Name="ParentUniformGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />

                  </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                  <DataTemplate>


                    <ItemsControl>


                      <Grid Height="{Binding ElementName=stretchedLabel, Path=ActualHeight}"
                            VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                          <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                          <RowDefinition
Height="{Binding ElementName=ParentUniformGrid,Path=DataContext.SplitterSize}" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Image VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Grid.Row="0"
                               HorizontalAlignment="Center" x:Name="ProductImage" Source="{Binding Converter={Utilities:ProductImageConverter}}"
                               Height="{Binding ImageHeight}" MaxHeight="{Binding ImageHeight}" MouseLeftButtonUp="BuyProductUsingImage" />
                        <Label Padding="0" Margin="0 1 0 0" Grid.Row="1" Background="LightGray"
                               VerticalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
                               HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                          <Label VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="1"
                                 HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Background="#fff"
                                 Padding="0" MaxWidth="{Binding ElementName=ShelvesControl, Path=DataContext.PriceLabelWidthSize}"
                                 Width="{Binding ElementName=ShelvesControl, Path=DataContext.PriceLabelWidthSize}">
                            <Viewbox VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                     HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                              <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
                                          VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="1" Background="#fff" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                                <Label Background="Yellow" Padding="2 0 2 0"
                                       VerticalContentAlignment="Bottom" FontWeight="Bold" Content="{Binding Price}">
                                </Label>
                              </StackPanel>
                            </Viewbox>
                          </Label>
                        </Label>


                      </Grid>


                    </ItemsControl>
                  </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
              </ItemsControl>
            </TextBlock>

          </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
      </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>

  </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: Can you provide XAMl of the UserControl which bound to so large DataContext?

Comment: @sll Updated the question with the XAML :)

Comment: Are you using ListView for the root ItemsControl? Is there any ScrollViewer? Try out using ListView for root ItemsControl and set `<ListView ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled="True"`

Comment: There is a ScrollViewer, but thats not the problem. The scrolling works perfect. The problem is that it uses so much time to draw all the UIElements. I'm trying to optimize the itemscontrol. The best thing would be if you could have one thread for each UserControl. There are no dependency between each UserControl except that they are UIElement and WPF using only one thread for drawing these elements :/ Too bad, as most of the processors today have more than one core.

Comment: Have you tried ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled="True"?

Answer (score 0):

For `DataGrid`, I found this article:
http://wpf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=SelectAll%28%29%20Performance&referringTitle=Tips%20%26%20Tricks&ProjectName=wpf

and also
http://wpf.codeplex.com/discussions/66291?ProjectName=wpf

Perhaps it already helps.

Answer (score 0):

There's more to virtualizing an `ItemsControl` than just setting `VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing`. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2783845/302677) for more details

Basically your `ItemsControl.Template` needs a `ScrollViewer` to enable Virtualization. I suspect that once you get your `ItemsControl` is virtualizing correctly, you'll see a dramatic improvement in performance.

Virtualization means that only the visible items are rendered. When you scroll, the UI containers get re-used and just the `DataContext` behind them changes. This means that instead of drawing 2000 records, you would only be drawing about 20 (or however many are visible)

Comment: As strange as it sounds, all the elements are visible at once :/

Comment: @Numm3n Have you tried setting breakpoints and figuring out which piece takes so long? For example, is it the data access, or is it rendering the UI elements?

Answer (score 0):

Doing the same without the `ViewBox` and the bindings to `ActualWidth` and `ActualHeight` will help a lot, if it is feasible to replace with an lighter alternative.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is only one way to get more UIThreads:

Every Window can have it's own UIThread (e.g).

http://eprystupa.wordpress.com/2008/07/28/running-wpf-application-with-multiple-ui-threads/

```
private void OnCreateNewWindow(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Thread thread = new Thread(() =>
    {
        Window1 w = new Window1();
        w.Show();

        w.Closed += (sender2, e2) =>
        w.Dispatcher.InvokeShutdown();

        System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run();
    });

    thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
    thread.Start();
}
```

Don't know, if that would be a solution for you, but you asked for more UIThreads ;)