# WPF Canvas-based ItemsControl with minimum recycled items?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, itemscontrol

I'm using an `ItemsControl` with a `Canvas` as its backing `Panel`. I often need to .Clear() the `ObservableCollection` is the ItemsControl's `ItemSource`, and then add new information to it, which causes all the controls to be destroyed and new `UserControl`s to be created, which is very sluggish. How can I force the ItemsControl to retain a certain amount of containers even after I call .Clear(), and then reuse them when new items are added to the ItemSource?

Comment: Have you searched the web for "itemscontrol virtualization"?

Comment: Yes, for many many hours. But Virtualization is for scrolling and not creating controls for things that are outside the ViewPort, my situation is different - the ViewPort doesn't change, only the underlying ItemSource changes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not sure how efficient this would be in your use case, but you might create a derived ItemsControl and override the `GetContainerForItemOverride` and `ClearContainerForItemOverride` methods to put and take item containers from a cache collection.

```
public class CachingItemsControl : ItemsControl
{
    private readonly Stack<DependencyObject> itemContainers =
        new Stack<DependencyObject>();

    protected override DependencyObject GetContainerForItemOverride()
    {
        return itemContainers.Count > 0
            ? itemContainers.Pop()
            : base.GetContainerForItemOverride();
    }

    protected override void ClearContainerForItemOverride(
        DependencyObject element, object item)
    {
        itemContainers.Push(element);
    }
}
```

Comment: In my use case, this caused a very dramatic improvement!

Comment: I've made a slight improvement and replaced `new ContentPresenter()` by `base.GetContainerForItemOverride()`. That makes the code completely independent from the actual container type.