# Is there a workaround to virtualize ItemsControl list while setting CanContentScroll = "false"?

Tags: wpf, xaml, scrollviewer, ui-virtualization

As I learned in [Virtualizing an ItemsControl?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2783845/1023939), I need to set

`ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll = "true"`

to be able to virtualize the list in my ItemsControl. However this causes a lot of scrolling issues including but not limited to bumpy scrolling and part of my expanded child to get cut off at the bottom of the window. I have googled this extensively and it seems like a lot of people are having issues with this. I however have yet to come across any workarounds.

Does anyone have a work around for this problem?

Answer (score 2):

There is no easy or simple workaround; the out-of-the-box `VirtualizingStackPanel` is what it is and can be somewhat limited. Most solutions require either writing a custom virtualizing panel or a virtualizing data provider. This blog post may help you find a solution that works for you:

http://bea.stollnitz.com/blog/?p=344

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can keep CanContentScroll = true and block scrolling with an other technic.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<ListView VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="False">` to disable virtualization of the stack panel in a listview. There may be a limitation of not being able to enable virtualization in that case, but you can try enabling it manually and seeing if it works.