# ItemsControl behavior when ItemsSource is IList

Tags: wpf, virtualization, itemscontrol, ilist, itemssource

I'm trying to implement a virtualizing collection for hierarchical controls similar to the one for regular controls presented in [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34405/WPF-Data-Virtualization).

The solution presented in the article relies heavily on the following behavior (from the article):

> When an `ItemsControl` is bound to an `IList` implementation, rather than
>   an `IEnumerable` implementation, it will not enumerate the entire list,
>   and instead only accesses the items required for display. It uses the
>   `Count` property to determine the size of the collection, presumably to
>   set the scroll extents. It will then iterate through the onscreen
>   items using the list indexer. Thus, it is possible to create an `IList`
>   that can report to have a large number of items, and yet only actually
>   retrieve the items when required.

I found that while `ListBox` has this behavior, `TreeView` (which is also an `ItemsControl`) doesn't behave like this, and all the items are always requested regardless of whether or not they're displayed on the screen.

So, is this a behavior specific just for `ListBox` and not for every `ItemsControl` or is it a bug in WPF's `TreeView`?

I've also been unable to find any mention of this behavior on MSDN, so if anyone finds it documented anywhere I'd love to know about it.

Comment: In the *Remarks* section of [ItemsControl.ItemsPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemspanel.aspx) it says that the default ItemsPanel for ListBox is [VirtualizingStackPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.virtualizingstackpanel.aspx), and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747277.aspx#TreeView_Style) MSDN says that the default ItemsPanel for TreeView is an ordinary StackPanel.

Comment: @Clemens This happens even when setting `TreeView.ItemsPanel` to `VirtualizingStackPanel` and turning on virtualization with `VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"`.

Comment: Ok, you could have mentioned that in your question.

Answer (score 0):

There's more to Virtualizing an `ItemsControl` than just using a `VirtualizingStackPanel` or setting `VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"`

Here's the important bits of code needed, but see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2783845/302677) for more complete answer

```
<ItemsControl
    VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True" <!-- needed -->
    ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" <!-- needed -->
    ... >
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <VirtualizingStackPanel /> <!-- needed -->
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.Template>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <ScrollViewer>  <!-- needed -->
                <ItemsPresenter  />
            </ScrollViewer>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.Template>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: Actually, setting `TreeView.ItemsPanel` to `VirtualizingStackPanel` and `VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"` is enough to turn on virtualization in a `TreeView` - I used Snoop and saw that `TreeViewItems` were only created for the visible items; but apparently, UI virtualization doesn't necessarily mean that non-visible items won't be accessed. So my question is less about UI virtualization and more about how to make a `TreeView` only access visible elements from its `ItemsSource` (just like `ListBox` does).