# Performance degredation with custom ListBox ControlTemplate

Tags: wpf, mvvm, listbox, controltemplate

Using a template for a custom control deriving from `ListBox` causes filtering of `ItemSource` to become slow. The filtering is done in the get of the `ItemSource` that the control is bound to. This problem is not present when a normal `ListBox` is used, so why should it be any different for a custom `ListBox`?

Filtering:

```
public IEnumerable<LibraryViewModel> Libraries {
    get {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.LibrarySearchString))
            return _libraries.Where(lib => IsLibraryMatch(lib, this.LibrarySearchString));
        else
            return _libraries.OrderBy(lib => !lib.IsFavourite);
    }
}
```

Using the control:

```
<con:FilterListBox Grid.Row="1"
                   ItemsSource="{Binding Libraries}"
                   SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedLibrary}"
                   ItemTemplate="{StaticResource  
                                  LibraryItemTemplate}"                           
                   SearchString="{Binding LibrarySearchString, Mode=TwoWay}"
                   IsSearching="False"
                   Margin="4"/>
```

The control template:

```
<Style x:Key="{x:Type con:FilterListBox}" TargetType="{x:Type con:FilterListBox}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type con:FilterListBox}">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <DockPanel Grid.Row="0">
                        <TextBlock Text="Search"
                                    VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent},
                                                Path=SearchString,
                                                UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                 Margin="4,0,0,0"/>
                    </DockPanel>

                    <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1" CanContentScroll="True">
                        <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True"
                                    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                    </ScrollViewer>

                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1"
                               Text="Searching..."
                               HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                               VerticalAlignment="Center"
                               Visibility="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent},
                                                    Path=IsSearching,
                                                    Converter={StaticResource CollapsedIfFalseConverter}}"/>
                </Grid>

            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The slow behavior of your `FilterListBox` may come with an Virtualization issue. You replaced the ItemsHost of the `ListBox` with a simple `StackPanel`. By default, the ListBox uses a `VirtualizingStackPanel`, which virtualizes the Items whenever possible. See the default ListBox Template as a reference. If you have a simple StackPanel as ItemsPresenter, the ListBox has to re-render every item when your filter changes. Depending on the number of items, this can cause your slow behavior. Try to use the default itemshost instead. You should also know, that virtualization is only possible with 'simple' items (same Height for every item basically).

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer, I will give it a go tomorrow. I have around 1000 items in my list and yes if I make this much less, then the perormance issue goes away, so I am sure you are correct!

Comment: It should be noted that there may be more to Virtualizing your ListBox than just using a `VirtualizingStackPanel`. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2784220/302677) for more details

Comment: +1 Yes I forgot to mention. You have to set some more properties to get it virtualized. The answer in Rachel's link offers everything which is required. Thank you.