# How to stop user from selecting items in a listbox without disabling it

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox

There is something i need to do, list something in WPF but i don't want the users to click on the list, the list box does not have a property to disable selection. You can disable the control, but that's not what i need, because it messes with the styles and makes the text difficult to read. I mean there is something like:

```xaml
<ListBox IsEnabled="{Binding IsValid}" ...> ... </ListBox>
```

I wonder if there is something like:

```xaml
<ListBox Selection="Disabled" ...> ... </ListBox>
```

Or if there exists an alternative to listing items different to a list box

The question is, is there a way to list content in WPF and that the users can't select those items??

Comment: You may use an [`ItemsControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.aspx).

Comment: If you have to use a `ListBox` for whatever reason(like showing over state but not let them select it), just set `SelectedIndex` to -1 in the SelectionChanged event. `lb.SelectionChanged += (sender, args) => lb.SelectedIndex = -1;`

Comment: @viv  I had tried to do that in the set of the SelectedIndex and it does not work but in SelectionChanged event it does work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [ItemsControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in place of `ListBox`. ItemsControl is a [lookless control](http://drwpf.com/blog/2009/05/12/itemscontrol-l-is-for-lookless/).

But *virtualization is not supported (by default) for ItemsControl*, you have to do some changes to support virtualization(*in case you want*).

Refer to this if you want to support virtualization here - [Virtualizing an ItemsControl.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2783845/virtualizing-an-itemscontrol)

---

Either you can set [IsHitTestVisible](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.ishittestvisible%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to `false` on *ListBoxItem* which disallows any mouse inputs on it. You can set it using *ItemContainerStyle*.

```
    <ListBox>
        <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                <Setter Property="IsHitTestVisible" Value="False"/>
            </Style>
        </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ListBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the MVVM pattern, your `ViewModel` should be keeping track of `SelectedItems`. You can bind this to the `ListBox.SelectedItems` property so that it stays in sync.

You can have the `ViewModel` control the validation logic for selecting items. `ListBox.SelectionChanged` event can be hooked into and with a property on the model, like `CanSelect` you can selectively select items.