# How to make a WPF listbox item not clickable

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm, .net-4.0

I am using a listbox to display a list of items that I am selecting programmatically in a voice activated program. Is there any way to keep the selected item from being clicked on? I do want mouse over functionality, just not clicking on the actual item.

I have tried to set Focusable (does not do anything for what I want) and IsEnabled (disables mouse over)

Here is my current style:

```
<Style x:Key="GlyphList" TargetType="ListBox">
    <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
      <Setter.Value>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
          <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" IsEnabled="False"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
      </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
      <Setter.Value>
        <DataTemplate DataType="models:SpellingGlyph">
          <Label VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
            <Label.Template>
              <ControlTemplate>
                <Grid>
                  <TextBlock Name="MainText" Text="{Binding Text}" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="0,0,5,0"/>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                  <DataTrigger Value="True">
                    <DataTrigger.Binding>
                      <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ObjectReferenceEqualityConverter}">
                        <Binding />
                        <Binding Path="SelectedItem" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=ListBox}"/>
                      </MultiBinding>
                    </DataTrigger.Binding>
                    <Setter TargetName="MainText" Property="Foreground" Value="#75BAFF"/>
                    <Setter TargetName="MainText" Property="FontWeight" Value="SemiBold"/>
                    <Setter TargetName="MainText" Property="FontSize" Value="22"/>
                  </DataTrigger>
                  <DataTrigger Value="True">
                    <DataTrigger.Binding>
                      <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MultiBooleanConverter}"> <!--SelectedItem trumps mouse over-->
                        <Binding ElementName="MainText" Path="IsMouseOver"/>
                        <Binding Path="SelectedItem" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=ListBox}" Converter="{StaticResource InvertedNullCheckToBooleanConverter}"/>
                      </MultiBinding>
                    </DataTrigger.Binding>
                    <Setter TargetName="MainText" Property="Foreground" Value="#75BAFF"/>
                    <Setter TargetName="MainText" Property="FontWeight" Value="SemiBold"/>
                    <Setter TargetName="MainText" Property="FontSize" Value="22"/>
                  </DataTrigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
              </ControlTemplate>
            </Label.Template>
          </Label>
        </DataTemplate>
      </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
  </Style>
```

Comment: just disable the ItemContainer by setting the ItemContainerStyle. What have you tried?

Comment: Updated my answer....disabling the container makes mouse over not work

Comment: Similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20957029/how-to-stop-user-from-selecting-items-in-a-listbox-without-disabling-it

Comment: Have you tried making it HitTestVisible or not?

Comment: @Tejs yes, sorry forgot to specify that one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<ListBox PreviewMouseDown="ListBox_OnPreviewMouseDown"..

private void ListBox_OnPreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

Comment: I swear I looked for a mouse down....just was blind. I had a separate solution that I will post, but I actually like this better as this is more of a UI concern than something I should handle in the VM

Answer (score 1):

Simply set `IsHitTestVisible` to `false`

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.ishittestvisible(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution to what I accepted was to add the following in my view model:

```
     if (_viewModelSetSelectedGlyph != value) return;
    _selectedGlyph = value;
    OnPropertyChanged("SelectedGlyph");
```

Then, set the `_viewModelSetSelectedGlyph` each time before actually setting the `SelectedGlyph`. Then, when the UI tries to set the `SelectedGlyph`, it would not succeed, only when the view model sets it by also setting the private variable does it succeed.