# ItemsControl rendering slowly

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, wpf-controls, itemscontrol

I am using an ItemsControl for showing alist of items and itrs xaml is like

```
<ItemsControl  ItemsSource="{Binding ShelfItemsCollection}" Name="shelfGridView" Margin="5" >
<ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>   
        <Stackpanel>                        
        <Image Width="150" Height="200" Stretch="Fill" Source="{Binding CoverImage}" ></Image> 
        +
        some other infos
        </Stackpanel>
        </DataTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
<ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
<ItemsPanelTemplate>                    
            <WrapPanel  Orientation="Horizontal" />                    
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
```

The problem i am facing is i had almost 100 items in list and i am doing some filtering operations on the list based on some properties and limit the results to a lesser no ( say 20 items at a time)for doing this filtering it took a lot of time to refresh and load the list view .
 This is the code i used for filtering

```
ICollectionView dataView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(shelfGridView.ItemsSource);
dataView.Filter = CloudFilter;
dataView.Refresh();
private bool CloudFilter(object item)
{
MyObject lib = item as MyObject;
return lib.Property !=valuetofilter; 
}
```

Is any way to improve the perfomance or any specific reason for slow rendering ?

Comment: Are you using filter to limit the items as 20?

Comment: Limit the items based on some properties , u can see CloudFilter() , Based on a property value , for example if property.Contains("Japan") , then it shows only records related to term Japan ,Its not necessary that the count is going to be 20. i edited the question as well

Comment: Post more code let us test with your example and your data structure.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/3CRBLnU2 Here is the code of xaml and c# . Hav to use some hardcoded values for testing .

Answer (score 5):

**ItemsControl doesn't support UI virtualization out of the box**. Either use ListBox or make ItemsControl UI virtualized.

You can enable UI virtualization on ItemsControl by following some steps :

1. Set `VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"` on ItemsControl.
2. Set `ItemsPanel` to be `VirtualizingStackPanel`.
3. Override `ControlTemplate` of ItemsControl and wrap `ItemsPresenter` inside `ScrollViewer`.
4. Set `ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"` on ItemsControl.

Details for the above proposal can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2784220/632337).

---

Moreover, you are setting `ItemsSource` directly to SourceCollection i.e. `ShelfItemsCollection` and later filtering it by getting defualtView created underneath for that collection. Binding directly with sourceCollection will force `ItemsControl`(non-Virtualized ofcourse) to generate 100 containers to host your underlying objects.

Instead you should create `ICollectionView` with filter predicate set on it and bind `ItemsSource` to that instance. May be you can also create `CollectionViewSource` and bind with it. If you bind with filtered instance, it will generate only 20 containers (non-virtualized ItemsControl).
Ofcourse, **enabling UI virtualization on ItemsControl, will generate containers for only visible UI items on GUI.**

Comment: "ItemsControl doesn't support UI virtualization" "Either use ListBox or make ItemsControl UI virtualized.". If it doesn't support virtualization how can you make it UI virtualized. Doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Konrad perhaps a better phrasing would be, "does not support UI virtualization out of the box"