# Application starts lagging after switching tabs

Tags: wpf, tabcontrol, caliburn.micro

I'm tryig to use TabControl in Caliburn micro WPF project. I have two ViewModels (userControls) and I want the user to switch between them using tabcontrol.

I tried two different approaches, but I get the same problem with both of them. 
After switching tabs (I click on second tab and then back on first), my application starts visibly lagging. For example if I click on a checkbox there is a visible delay.

It is the same problem as in this question: [TabControl becoming very laggy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22579798/tabcontrol-becoming-very-laggy), difference is that I am using caliburn micro and I am not sure that ListBox would be appropriate in my situation.

I tried implementing it this way:

```
  <TabControl>
      <TabItem Header="Item1">
            <ContentControl
                    x:Name="Item1"/>
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem Header="Item2">
                <ContentControl
                    x:Name="Item2"/>
            </TabItem>
        </TabControl>
```

I also tried using Conductor.Collection.OneActive:

```
this.Items.Add(Item1);
this.Items.Add(Item2);
```

XAML:

```
<TabControl Name="Items"/>
```

Everything works fine, it loads fast, tab switching is fast. The only problem is that rendering performance is really bad.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What goes in your tabitems? How's it and any viewmodel instantiated - what's in there that could take time?

Comment: @Andy: I actually commented everything out, so now  the second tab is completely empty. The lag is a bit better, but still quite noticable. 
In the first tab I have a chart made by LiveChart library. When panning and zooming the lag is most noticable. But only after switching tabs.


I do it like this:

`Item1= new Item1ViewModel(events);`
`Item2= new Item2ViewModel(events);`
`this.Items.Add(Item1);`
`this.Items.Add(Item2);`

Comment: is it possible to have the complete project on github for example, because its impossible to understant the problem with these few lines of code...?

Comment: how are the viewmodels loaded for the tabs? are you using DI and what is the lifetime of each viewmodel?