# Adding Scrollbar to ItemsControl

Tags: wpf, data-binding, xa

I have a long list coming from my Business logic which I need to display on the UI. As the list is long, I tried adding Scrollviewer but I am unable to scroll.

please find the XAML code below

```
<Grid Margin="0,32,0,0">
                                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding IDC_WiFi, Source={StaticResource Resources}}" FontFamily="Segoe UI" FontSize="20" Foreground="#4cb5ab" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                                                <Button Command="{Binding HardwareWifiAccordionCommand}" BorderThickness="0" Width="16" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="16" >
                                                    <Button.Background>
                                                        <ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding AccordionImageHardwareWifi}" />
                                                    </Button.Background>
                                                </Button>
                                            </Grid>
                                            <TextBlock Text="Klein's, Anil's" FontFamily="Segoe UI" FontSize="15" Foreground="#8fa3ad"/>
                                            <StackPanel  Height="200" Visibility="{Binding IsAccordionHardwareWifi, Converter={StaticResource Bool2Visible}}">
                                                <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                                                    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding WifiList,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" >
                                                        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>


                                                            <DataTemplate>

                                                                <StackPanel Margin="0,32,0,0">

                                                                    <Grid>
                                                                        <Image Source="/Images/Assets/da_wifi1_16x16.png" Height="16" Width="16" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                                                                        <TextBlock Margin="25,0,0,0" Text="{Binding NetworkName}" FontSize="15" Foreground="#FFFFFF" />
                                                                        <TextBlock Text="" FontSize="15" Foreground="#8fa3ad" HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
                                                                    </Grid>
                                                                    <TextBlock Text="" FontSize="15" Foreground="#8fa3ad" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />

                                                                </StackPanel>

                                                            </DataTemplate>
                                                        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>

                                                    </ItemsControl>
                                                </ScrollViewer>
                                            </StackPanel>
```

Comment: not happenning for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The scrollviewer needed a **Height**  to be set

```
<Grid Margin="0,32,0,0">
                                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding IDC_WiFi, Source={StaticResource Resources}}" FontFamily="Segoe UI" FontSize="20" Foreground="#4cb5ab" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                                                <Button Command="{Binding HardwareWifiAccordionCommand}" BorderThickness="0" Width="16" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="16" >
                                                    <Button.Background>
                                                        <ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding AccordionImageHardwareWifi}" />
                                                    </Button.Background>
                                                </Button>
                                            </Grid>
                                            <TextBlock Text="Klein's, Anil's" FontFamily="Segoe UI" FontSize="15" Foreground="#8fa3ad"/>
                                            <StackPanel  Height="200" Visibility="{Binding IsAccordionHardwareWifi, Converter={StaticResource Bool2Visible}}">
                                                <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Height="350">
                                                    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding WifiList,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" >
                                                        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>


                                                            <DataTemplate>

                                                                <StackPanel Margin="0,32,0,0">

                                                                    <Grid>
                                                                        <Image Source="/Images/Assets/da_wifi1_16x16.png" Height="16" Width="16" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                                                                        <TextBlock Margin="25,0,0,0" Text="{Binding NetworkName}" FontSize="15" Foreground="#FFFFFF" />
                                                                        <TextBlock Text="" FontSize="15" Foreground="#8fa3ad" HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
                                                                    </Grid>
                                                                    <TextBlock Text="" FontSize="15" Foreground="#8fa3ad" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />

                                                                </StackPanel>

                                                            </DataTemplate>
                                                        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>

                                                    </ItemsControl>
                                                </ScrollViewer>
                                            </StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put it into a `ScrollViewer`.

```
<ScrollViewer>
        <StackPanel >

        </StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Answer (score 0):

As @StepUp points out you can just wrap it with a ScrollViewer but I believe this breaks virtualization. That's outside the scope of this question of course but it's something to keep in mind. If performance is likely to become an issue then I'd suggest implementing this as shown in [the answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2783845/virtualizing-an-itemscontrol).