# ItemsControl Not Virtualizing

Tags: c#, wpf, ui-virtualization

I cannot get this `ItemsControl` to virtualize properly.  Debugging shows that the collection is initialized quickly, but all the items are being added to the control instead of a subset (I simply put a TracePoint in the TextBox_Initialize`event in the`UserControl` that makes up the item).

Note: I have looked at other, similar questions, but have been unable to solve this issue with those answers.

The ViewModel:

```
public class ImportInformationViewModel : CommandViewModel
{
    public ImportInformationViewModel()
    {

        this.PropertyChanged += ImportInformationViewModel_PropertyChanged;
    }

    private ObservableCollection<SingleTransactionViewModel> mTransactions;
    public ReadOnlyObservableCollection<SingleTransactionViewModel> Transactions
    {
        get
        {
            if (mTransactions == null)
                mTransactions = new ObservableCollection<SingleTransactionViewModel>();

            var filtered = mTransactions.Where(trans => !trans.IgnoreTransaction)
                .OrderBy(trans => trans.DateStamp)
                .ThenBy(trans => trans.TransactionName)
                .ThenBy(trans => trans.TransactionDetail);

            return new ReadOnlyObservableCollection<SingleTransactionViewModel>(new ObservableCollection<SingleTransactionViewModel>(filtered));
        }
    }

    private void ImportInformationViewModel_PropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.PropertyName == "TransactionFileName")
        {
            if (File.Exists(mTransactionFileName))
           {
                mTransactions.Clear();
                // Process File (Not Shown)
                mTransactions.Add(new SingleTransactionViewModel()
                {
                    DateStamp = date,
                    TransactionDetail = someText;
                });
            }
        }

        if (e.PropertyName != "Transactions")
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Transactions");
    }
}
```

`SingleTransactionViewModel` is just another class that implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`.  Nothing special.

Here is the control containing the `ItemsControl`

```
<UserControl x:Class="ImportInformationView">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="TransactionsData" Source="{Binding Transactions}">
            <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
                <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="YearAndMonth" />
            </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
        </CollectionViewSource>

        <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="booleanToVisibility" />
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource TransactionsData}}"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                        HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                        ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"
                        VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"
                        VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling"
                        MinHeight="20">
            <ItemsControl.GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle>
                    <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                            <Setter Property="Template">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                                        <GroupBox Padding="5" Margin="2,5">
                                            <GroupBox.Header>
                                                <Border Background="Black"
                                                        CornerRadius="4">
                                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                                                </Border>
                                            </GroupBox.Header>
                                            <ItemsPresenter />
                                        </GroupBox>
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Style>
                    </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                </GroupStyle>
            </ItemsControl.GroupStyle>
            <ItemsControl.Template>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <ScrollViewer CanContentScroll="True">
                        <ItemsPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding UIElement.SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.Template>
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <UniformGrid IsItemsHost="True" Columns="2" Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True" VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True" />
                    <!--<VirtualizingStackPanel IsItemsHost="True" />-->
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <views:SingleTransactionView Margin="4,6" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </UserControl>
```

And I've boiled the `SingleTransactionView` down to something very simple:

```
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="ExpanderColumn" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" SharedSizeGroup="TransactionNameColumn" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="DateColumn" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="OptionsColumn" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>


    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1"
               Grid.Row="0"
               Initialized="TextBlock_Initialized"
               Text="{Binding TransactionName}"
               HorizontalAlignment="Left"
               VerticalAlignment="Center"
               FontSize="14"
               FontWeight="Bold"
               Margin="4"/>        
</Grid>
```

Comment: UniformGrid does not support virtualizing.

Comment: @Clemens - actually, I believe I've used `UniformGrid` as a `VirtualizingPanel` before.  Regardless, if I replace `UniformGrid` with the commented out `VirtualizingStackPanel` above, it still does not virtualize.  I have looked at the other answers, but none has helped me overcome this issue.

Comment: I'm curious if anyone can provide an answer that goes beyond what's explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2783845/1136211

Comment: Me too.  :)  Between previous work that I've done and this example, I cannot find the error of my ways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably due to your use of grouping.  By default, enabling grouping effectively switches off virtualization.  However, as of .NET 4.5, you should be able to regain this functionality via the `VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizingWhenGrouping` property.

Excerpt from [this blog post](http://www.jonathanantoine.com/2011/10/07/wpf-4-5-%E2%80%93-part-11-new-features-for-the-virtualizingpanel/) on WPF enhancements in .NET 4.5:

> In WPF 4.0, you lost virtualization when grouping is done on the collection you display. I repeat : **Grouping = no virtualization in WPF 4.0.** This is still the default behavior of WPF 4.5, **but you can turn on the virtualization by using the `IsVirtualizingWhenGrouping` attached property of the `VirtualizingPanel` class**. When this is done, you benefit of all the already described advantages of virtualization.
>
> Here is how you can enable it via XAML:
>
> ```
> <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Persons}"
>          ItemTemplate="{StaticResource PersonDataTemplate}"
>          VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"
>          VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizingWhenGrouping="True">
>     <ListBox.GroupStyle>
>         <GroupStyle HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource GroupHeaderTemplate}" />
>     </ListBox.GroupStyle>
> </ListBox>
> ```

Sounds like setting `VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizingWhenGrouping="True"` alongside your other virtualization-related properties should give you the behavior you want.+